# Coldfusion Regex-ing logic acting strangely

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I start with entries like this in a spreadsheet:

[image: spreadsheetPic]

*Notice the different size dashes*.. Longer one after Permit Date. Chr(8211) if I am correct.

I turn the spreadsheet into a query:

[image: queryPic]

I get a cell value and regex that first bit out of it. (Regex pattern seems a bit much but it works)

```
//i make a new query and set one cell
querysetcell(newquery,"permitDateHeader",rereplace(cellWithPermitDate,
  "^[(\W)]*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(:| -| –)+","","all"), insertRow);
```

However, I still am left with this:

[image: wrongoutput]

Notice the regex worked on the Construction Type with just the two small dashes.

[image: rightoutput]

So I created a test page .cfm (this other stuff was running in a controller)

```
number = "Permit Number:  2016-1";
date = "- Permit Date – January 13, 2016";
reformednumber = rereplace(number,"^[(\W)]*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(:| -| –)+","","all");
reformeddate = rereplace(date,"^[(\W)]*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(:| -| –)+","","all");
writeDump(reformednumber);
writeDump(reformeddate);
```

And this is what is dumped:

[image: pagedump]

Permit date was successfully parsed. This time on a .cfm page rather than in the controller and putting it in a query. That's the only difference I see. same regex.

Why is this happening?

Possible solution is just changing the regex. I just didn't want to pick up values that fall under the \W scope such as a dollar sign.

*Note* if this **can't be recreated** then it may be too 'application-specific' of an error to be left on the forum.

Comment: You might want to remove the `"all"` parameter in your `rereplace` since you only want to discard the first occurence of the pattern.

Comment: If you think the long hyphen is char(8211), why are you not taking that into account in your regex?  By the way, the ColdFusion asc() function will tell you what that character actually is.

Comment: @DanBracuk
you're right, but I tried that and was left with @%~  or some strange characters in place of the dash in the output. Didn't play with that a whole lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am **still not sure** why that happened, but this edit to the regex seems to have **fixed it**.

```
^[(\W)]*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(\s)*(\w)*(\s)*(\W)?
//used(\W)? at the end rather than (:| -| –)+
```

Comment: The wide dash `–` was probably improperly encoded in your regexp. CF tends to screw up Unicode in templates when saved without BOM.

Comment: I was going to recommend \s instead of " " since we've run into past issues with space-like unicode characters.  Occasionally when copying-and-pasting values from MS products, a "non-breaking space" is introduced. The value isn't viewable and isn't automatically trimmed using CF's trim() either.

Comment: @JamesMoberg what confuses me still is that the same value (long dash) i copied and pasted, worked differently between the straight test view and the controller.

Comment: @MattWilde Save your document as UTF-8 with BOM and test it. It does work for me, yes.